# Error I've never seen before! An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, kernel32

Well I've gotten an error I've never seen before, does anyone know why it is happening?

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
"

Stack Trace

```
    StackTrace  "   at System.String..ctor(SByte* value)\r\n   at System.StubHelpers.CSTRMarshaler.ConvertToManaged(IntPtr cstr)\r\n   at SharpTUI.dlls.Kernal32.GetConsoleTitle(String& lpConsoleTitle, UInt32 size)\r\n   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)\r\n   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)\r\n   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()\r\n   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()"   string
```

CODE:

```
        uint x = Kernal32.GetConsoleTitle(out windowTitle, 9999);
        IntPtr ip = User32.FindWindow(null, windowTitle);
        User32.GetWindowRect(ip, ref windowRect);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint GetConsoleTitle(
           out string lpConsoleTitle,
           uint size);
```

Comment: check this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164911.aspx

Comment: That's what happens when you get a [DllImport] wrong.  [Get it right](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/GetConsoleTitle.html) and be sure to set the Capacity high enough.

Comment: omg I had to up the capacity... The error looked so intimidating, yet the solution was so simple.